# How to fix GROMACS error 'No such moleculetype SOL'?

Tags: chemistry

I'm trying to reproduce this tutorial: http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/lysozyme/04_ions.html but with a different protein.

During the step of adding ions (using genion for ion.tpr file generation)I get the 'No such moleculetype SOL'. When I add the SOL in the moleculetype section, I get 'Moleculetype 'protein' has no atoms'.

Any help is appreciated!

I'm providing the relevant parts of topol.top file.

[ atomtypes ]
;name   bond_type     mass     charge   ptype   sigma         epsilon       Amb
...

[ moleculetype ]
;name            nrexcl
protein          3

[ atoms ]
...
...

[ system ]
protein in water

[ molecules ]
; Compound        nmols
protein           1
SOL             53832

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

About SOL error-It seems like your topol.top does not have water topology file. Add line anywhere in topol.top and remove SOL from moleculetype section.
#include "oplsaa.ff/spce.itp"

About protein error- Check if your *.gro file include 1 protein molecule and 53832 water molecule in it. I am suspicious your *.gro file does not have protein molecule and filled with water only. Make sure the number of molecules in topol.top should be same with in the *.gro file.